# How to ban the ConvertBack value in IValueConverter

Tags: c#, uwp

I use IValueConverter to bind an enum to three RadioButton.

When the RadioButton is checked that I will use ConvertBack to set the value.

But I find I dont know how to write the `ConvertBack`

```
public ImageShackEnum KkaHsa { get; set; }

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
{
    if (value is true)
    {
        return MyEnum;
    }

    //If I return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue that will throw.            
}
```

I cant find the [Binding.DoNothing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.donothing(v=vs.110).aspx) in uwp that I use it in wpf.

I define a new enum value to solve it but I think it may exist another way to solve it.

Comment: I usually just write `throw new NotSupportedException();` in the ConvertBack

Comment: @kurakura88 I need the value when its true.

Answer (score 1):

You can invalidate the `ConvertBack` operation if you return a incompatible value - ideally `null`. In this case it cannot be assigned back to the property in view model and system will ignore it and will instead respond to the `IsChecked == true` `RadioButton`, that gets selected.

Alternative approach would be to create multiple properties, one `bool` property for each state of the enum, and one overall `SelectedValue`. For example:

public MyEnum SelectedValue {...}

```
public bool ValueIsOptionA 
{
    get => SelectedValue == MyEnum.OptionA;
    set => SelectedValue = MyEnum.OptionA; 
}

public bool ValueIsOptionB
{
    get => SelectedValue == MyEnum.OptionB; 
    set => SelectedValue = MyEnum.OptionB; 
}

public bool ValueIsOptionC 
{
    get => SelectedValue == MyEnum.OptionC; 
    set => SelectedValue = MyEnum.OptionC; 
}
```

And then bind each `RadioButton.IsChecked` to its respective `ValueIsOptionX` property.

Clearly, this solution causes more code duplication, but it avoids the "dirty hack" with `null` value.